# IntelliJ is not able to recognize behave run options in feature file [behave python BDD library]

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, python-behave

**1. Intellij is not able to recognize the Run options in the feature file, while able to run the file using the command-line tool.**

getting Nothing here.
[image]

**2. There is even no option in the right-click menu**

[image]

**3. Steps are identified as not implemented while steps are implemented and executing successfully with `behave` CLI tool**

Comment: Seems the Behave Configuration is available only for Intellij Ultimate, which's not available for the community version. Very disappointing :(

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal, since as you say the ideal is to have the appropriate version of IntelliJ. However, a workaround that has saved me in these situations is to select the step I want to go to and use Ctrl+Shift+F to search in the whole project the place where the method is declared.

This command is also useful to know in which Scenarios a certain step is used, because even if you have the Professional version of IntelliJ it only allows you to access from the Scenario to the Step and not the other way around.